# Decoding binary received over tcp socket in c#?

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp, binary, tcpclient

I have several linux routers setup that sniff nearby traffic. They have sockets open in order for an application to be connected over tcp, through the sockets data is streamed in binary.

I've built a simple application to check if data is being received, and it is, however, it's giberish. Seems like binary isn't decoded properly. Does anyone have any clue?

```
        try
        {
            TcpClient ourMagicClient = new TcpClient();
            ourMagicClient.Connect("192.168.0.101", Port);
            NetworkStream ourStream = ourMagicClient.GetStream();
            byte[] data = new byte[ourMagicClient.ReceiveBufferSize];
            int offset = 0;

            for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
            {
                int bytesRead = ourStream.Read(data, 0, System.Convert.ToInt32(ourMagicClient.ReceiveBufferSize));
                output += Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, bytesRead);

                Console.WriteLine(output);
                //Console.WriteLine(encoding.); 
                Console.WriteLine("\n");
                offset = bytesRead;
            }

            System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"C:\Users\qweik_000\Desktop\WriteText.txt", output, Encoding.UTF8);

            Console.WriteLine("Press enter to close...");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error : " + e.Message);
            Console.WriteLine("Error : " + e.StackTrace);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

What I see in my console app upon running it :

[image]

Comment: If binary data is being received why are you converting it to a string? What do you expect to see?

Comment: sniffed traffic tends to be unreadable binary data... Ask these Experts from NSA how to make sense out  of it...

Comment: @Qweick are you sure the other side is sending you a long string , and not some object ?

Comment: @DanielKelley the data received should be strings representing sniffed traffic. Including sender, receiver mac addresses, rssi etc.

Comment: @eranotzap do you have any leads on how to check that? I don't have access to source code of the application that is streaming the data.

Comment: You might want to update your question then as it's confusing to mix binary and strings. Make it clear what is being sent.

Comment: It seems like he does not know .. 
Do you not know what object is being sent to you ...? 
Then you have no indication of how to read it.... That's an heavy question ..

What are you sniffing ..?

Comment: @eranotzap I'm using horst library to sniff wireless traffic on routers. https://github.com/br101/horst

Comment: a reply i've received from horst's developer was "The data is binary"

Comment: @Qweick do they have any examples there ?

Comment: @eranotzap there are no examples for clients that I could find.

Comment: network traffic is by definition binary. if you don't know ahead time the exact protocols in use, interpreting the data is a huge challenge. Do you have any idea what format this data is in? What makes you think that the code you wrote _should_ display intelligible information?

Comment: @PeterDuniho https://github.com/br101/horst/blob/master/network.c I'm not familiar with C, but that's source code for how data is written to a socket, specifically net_write and net_send_package functions.

Answer (score 0):

You might look for strings (some bytes in a row) of bytes in a valid ASCII range (i.e. 0x20 to 0x7f) and extract and display this "readable text" as a start...